# Trying to find gsl library, the only thing I can find is a loop in the system

Tags: linux, unix, gsl

I am working currently a little bit with wind data and I am using GSL and PlPlot to visualize and work with it.

When I try to add GSL or PlPlot libraries:

```
#include <gsl/gsl_errno.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_spline.h>
```

I get this message:

```
inter.c:4:27: fatal error: gsl/gsl_errno.h: No such file or directory
#include <gsl/gsl_errno.h>
                       ^
```

Far as I know, this means that I need to add the complete path to my library file, when I search for gsl then I get this:

```
find: File system loop detected; ‘/.snapshots/1/snapshot’ is part of the     same file system loop as ‘/’.
/.snapshots/2/snapshot/usr/share/doc/packages/gsl
/.snapshots/93/snapshot/usr/share/doc/packages/gsl
/.snapshots/94/snapshot/usr/share/doc/packages/gsl
```

I have read a little bit (still searching on the web), something went wrong with the installation of gsl? and plplot?. Strange as it appears is the same with math.h. There is a main difference here, because math.h is detected but gsl/plplot are not. How can I find my path to the library files and how can I eliminate that recursion?.

By the way, gsl and math were installed by default on SuSE at the begining and plplot was installed after using yast. Also I can find the GSL and PlPlot directories but the files are missing.

Thanks for any help guys.

Comment: Suse : # `zypper in gsl-devel` ... i.e. the -devel package is providing the headers.h and libraries for building applications with gsl. -

Comment: I am so embarrased... yes you are correct :). Thank you very much Knud.